# use the active CSS class on the current url

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In my php web project, I want to add a CSS class (.active) to the current url route when the user clicks on the navigation menu bar, i.e. my navigation menu.

```
<li><a href="http://localhost:8000/OhdyDaran')">Designation</a></li>
<li><a href="http://localhost:8000/gallery">Gallery</a></li>
<li><a href="http://localhost:8000/Introduction">introduction</a></li>
<li><a href="http://localhost:8000/home">Home</a></li>
```

How to Make an Application.active CSS class with Jquery or JS, after page refresh, is the link css applied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the url or path in this way:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname; // Returns path only
var url      = window.location.href;     // Returns full URL
```

And then, if the url or path is the same as the link, give it the `.active` class.

Comment: plz write complete code, there is confusion what u want to say ?

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var link = window.location.href.split('/');
   var page = link[link.length - 1];
   var url = link[link.length - 2];

   // now select the link based on the address
   $('li > a[href="'url + '/' + page + '"]').closest('li').addClass('active');
            })
```

Comment: thanks to reply, its working fine, problem another here, after page refresh active class disappear ? how fix it

Comment: @saeedahmed it working perfectly after page refresh.

Comment: I check it again, when I click on anchore tag class is applied. the page go to server side after response it disappeared again

Comment: $(function(){
    $('.nav a').filter(function(){
        return this.href==location.href}).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
    $('.nav a').click(function()
    {
        $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
    })
});

Comment: thanks above code that I pasted here is working perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<li class="ohdyDaran">
    <a href="http://localhost:8000/ohdyDaran')">Designation</a>
</li>
<li class="gallery">
    <a href="http://localhost:8000/gallery">Gallery</a>
</li>
<li class="introduction">
    <a href="http://localhost:8000/introduction">introduction</a>
</li>
<li class="home">
    <a href="http://localhost:8000/home">Home</a>
</li>

<script>
var url = window.location.href;
    var last = url.split('/');
    var clas= last[last.length-1];
    var nav = document.getElementsByClassName(clas)[0];
    nav.className = "active";
</script>
```